# Get data from local database using Django and Ajax by passing arguments to urls returns 404 error

Tags: python, json, ajax, django

I am trying to get data from my local database using Django and Ajax.
I set up a view where the user can get data and can pass in arguments to filter the data: start date, end date and site id.
Basically I want to pass arguments to views.py in order to filter data, but at the moment I don't really care if the params are reflected in the url or not, as long as the json returned is filtered based on the passed arguments.
When I test if I can successfully get the data from the database I am getting a page not found 404 error:
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://0.0.0.0:8000/acoustic_viz/get-data/?date_start=2016-10-28&date_end=2016-10-30&site_id=HENTONAOP

Error

Using the URLconf defined in acoustic_viz.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/

^get-data/

^get-sites/

^$

^static/(?P.*)$

The current URL, acoustic_viz/get-data/, didn't match any of these.

Is it because of the arguments that I passed? If so how can I change my urls.py so that Django is able to find the url with arguments?

Here is my code

acoustic_viz/index.html

```
var dateStart = {key:'2016-10-28'};
var dateEnd = {key:'2016-10-30'};
var siteID = {key:'HENTONAOP'};


$("#test").on('click',function(){
    console.log("test");
    $.getJSON('/acoustic_viz/get-data/', 
            {date_start: dateStart.key, date_end:dateEnd.key, site_id: siteID.key })        
        // when the data comes back from the server
        .done(function(data) {  
            console.log(data);
        });
});
```

acoustic_viz/acoustic_viz/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
import queries.views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^get-data/', queries.views.get_data),
    url(r'^get-sites/', queries.views.get_sites),
    url(r'^$', queries.views.hello_peeg),
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

acoustic_viz/queries/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import Data, Sites

import datetime
import json


class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
    """
    An HttpResponse that renders its content into JSON.
    """
    def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
        content = json.dumps(data)
        kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
        super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, **kwargs)


class CSVResponse(HttpResponse):
    """
    An HttpResponse that renders its contents as a CSV.

    'rows' should be a list of dict objects, with each entry corresponding to 1 CSV field.
    'fields' is the ordered list of field names in the CSV.
    """
    def __init__(self, rows, fields, **kwargs):

        csvfile = StringIO()

        # Write header with field names
        headerwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)    
        headerwriter.writerow(fields)

        # Write CSV rows
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fields, extrasaction='ignore')
        for row in rows:
            writer.writerow(row)


        kwargs['content_type'] = 'text/csv'
        super(CSVResponse, self).__init__(csvfile.getvalue(), **kwargs)
        self['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment'




def errorResponse(errormessage, format, extraJSON={}):
    """
    A nice standardized way to show the user an error message.
    """    

    if format == 'csv':
        return CSVResponse(
            [{'errormessage': errormessage}],
            fields=('errormessage',)  )

    else:
        json_objects = extraJSON.copy()
        json_objects['error'] = True
        json_objects['errormessage'] = errormessage
        return JSONResponse(json_objects)


def hello_peeg(request):
    return HttpResponse('hello peeg')

def get_sites(request):
    sites = Sites.objects.all().order_by('int_id')  
    json_objects = [{'site': (s.site_id + ', ' + s.site_name)} for s in sites]
    return JSONResponse({'sites': json_objects})

def get_data(request):
    filtered = False
    data = Data.objects.all().order_by('data_entry_id')
    startDate = request.GET.get('date_start')
    endDate = request.GET.get('date_end')
    siteID = request.GET.get('site_id')

    if startDate and endDate and siteID:
        filtered = True
        # __range: SELECT * WHERE date_recorded BETWEEN startDate and endDate;
        data = Data.objects.filter(date_recorded__range=(startDate, endDate), site_id=siteID)

    if not filtered: # error message if the user didn't supply an argument to filter the species list
        json_objects = [{'data': (d.date_recorded+ ' ' + d.time_recorded+ ' ' + d.average)} for d in data]
        #return errorResponse("Please supply a 'date_start', 'date_end', and 'site_id' argument.", format, {"data":[]})
    else:
        json_objects = [{'data': (d.data_entry_id + ' ' + d.site_id + ' ' + d.date_recorded+ ' ' + d.time_recorded+ ' ' + d.average)} for d in data]
        return JSONResponse({'data': json_objects})
```

This is my first attempt to write a Django app, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The core issue here is that you've used the "project app" as an "app in the project". You can do this, but that's why there's no prefix for the URLs. The [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project) explains the components early on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to open '/acoustic_viz/get-data/' but in urls.py all urls don't have `/acoustic_viz/` prefix. Try to change url in `index.html` template file

```
$.getJSON('/get-data/')
```

or add `acoustic_viz` to urls inside urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^acoustic_viz/get-data/', queries.views.get_data),
url(r'^acoustic_viz/get-sites/', queries.views.get_sites),
url(r'^$', queries.views.hello_peeg),
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Also note that you dont need to hardcode urls in django templates. You can name urls and use [url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#url) tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to end your url pattern with the **$** sign

You should have this

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^get-data/$', queries.views.get_data),
    url(r'^get-sites/$', queries.views.get_sites),
    url(r'^$', queries.views.hello_peeg),
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

instead of this

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^get-data/', queries.views.get_data),
    url(r'^get-sites/', queries.views.get_sites),
    url(r'^$', queries.views.hello_peeg),
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Do let me know if you run into any error,

Cheers!

Comment: I got the same error from before, but I figured out my problem, thanks!